# saving password for springboard webapps

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, passwords, springboard

I'm creating an html application using form authentication. If I open this application using Safari on iOS and complete the login screen, iOS asks me if I want to save my credentials.

but it doesn't work the same way if I add this webapp as a link on the springboard. In that case, iOS doesn't ask me to save my credentials.

Is there a way to force iOS to show me the possibility to save my credentials ?